# Tensorflow parameters for CNN

Tags: tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I created the below simple model (taken from a Coursera course). It has a total of five convolutions.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Note the input shape is the desired size of the image 300x300 with 3 bytes color
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300, 300, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    # The second convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The third convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fourth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # The fifth convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    # Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    # 512 neuron hidden layer
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    # Only 1 output neuron. It will contain a value from 0-1 where 0 for 1 class ('horses') and 1 for the other ('humans')
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

When I go through the summary, I can see that the `# of parameters` does not seem to match up with the theory that I have learned.

Summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 298, 298, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 149, 149, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 147, 147, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 73, 73, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 71, 71, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 35, 35, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 33, 33, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 16, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 14, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 7, 7, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3136)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 512)               1606144   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,704,097
Trainable params: 1,704,097
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The first value $448$ matches the formula:

```
(filter(width) * filter(height) * no_of_channels * no_of_filters_current * no_of_filters_previous ) + bias
```

$(3 * 3 * 3 * 16 * 1)+16$.

However the second value $4640$ does not add up for me.
I am supposed to get $(3 * 3 * 3 * 32 * 16)+32 = 13856$

Any idea where I am going wrong in the calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second calculation, there are three 3's instead of two. You can see that you are multiplying five terms instead of the four terms in your formula.

If you compute $(3 * 3 * 16 * 32) + 32$, you obtain $4640$.

Comment: but aren't there 3 channels (its an RGB) as you see in the input shape (300, 300, 3). Also in the first layer the ```no_of_filters_prev``` layer is 1

Comment: The 3 input channels are only in the first layer. In the second layer, the number of input channels is the number of output channels of the first one (i.e. 16).

Comment: Please, consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct if deemed so. Alternatively, please let me know if it is not clear.